# Why is が not used in the following situation?

Tags: particle-が, subjects

So the sentence is -

```
Naze sore o shimashita ka?
```

But isn't Naze the subject here and hence should have a が in front of it? I had read this in a text book that a subject is followed by が.

Comment: Why do you think *naze* (why) is the subject?

Comment: @aguijonazo Sorry, I understand now that it was a silly question.